# "up to now" versus "to now"

Tags: difference, prepositions

> From the beginning of the term **up to now**.
>
> From the beginning of the term **to now**.

Do you feel any difference between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence is not grammatical though. We normally say: ['up to now'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+now), '[up until now'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/until+now) or '[so far'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/so+far)

So, in your sentence "From the beginning of the term up to now." makes sense.

Comment: i agree with that - second sentence sounds grammatically incorrect